# synchronisation problem in multiple threads of multiple processes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization

I have a code. There are 2 processes. Parent is writer on file a.txt. Child is reader on a.txt.Parent has 2 threads and child has 2 threads. Parent's 1st thread opens a file parent1.txt . reads 128 chars. writes to a.txt.Parent's 2nd thread opens file parent2.txt.reads 128 chars. writes to a.txt. Child's 1st thread reads 128 chars from a.txt and writes to child1.txt. child's 2nd thread reads 128 chars from a.txt and child2.txt. Any parent thread , after writing, should generate event and invoke the child's reader threads.I have implemented a solution using mutex and condition variable.Parent's writer threads generate pthread_cond_signal after writing to a.txt. 1>But child's reader threads are not running after that. both parent threads are running in loop.2>Parent reads frm parent1.txt. the fread is successfull. But when it writes to a.txt, it is not successfull. the a.txt file is always empty.I think mutex can not be use between multiple processes. That may be 1 problem

```
My code is as follows


  #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;

FILE*fd,*fdRead1,*fdRead2,*fdWrite1,*fdWrite2;

pthread_mutex_t *mut1;
pthread_mutexattr_t attrmutex;

pthread_cond_t  *cond_var;
pthread_condattr_t attrcond;

#define OKTOWRITE "/condwrite"
#define MESSAGE "/msg"
#define MUTEX "/mutex_lock"

void* R1(void *)
{
    char buf[128];
    int size;
    fdWrite1 = fopen("child1.txt","w+");
    cout<<"R1Thread"<<endl; 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    cout<<"R1Thread-1"<<endl; 
        pthread_mutex_lock(mut1);
        pthread_cond_wait(cond_var,mut1);
    cout<<"R1Thread-2"<<endl; 
        size = fread(buf,128,1,fd);
        fwrite(buf,size,1,fdWrite1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mut1);
    }
    fclose(fdWrite1);
}

void* R2(void *)
{
    char buf[128];
    int size;
    fdWrite2 = fopen("child2.txt","w+");
    cout<<"R2Thread"<<endl; 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    cout<<"R2Thread-1"<<endl; 
        pthread_mutex_lock(mut1);
        pthread_cond_wait(cond_var,mut1);
    cout<<"R2Thread-2"<<endl; 
        size = fread(buf,128,1,fd);
        fwrite(buf,size,1,fdWrite2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mut1);

    }
    fclose(fdWrite2);

}


void* W1(void *)
{
    char buf[128];
    int size;
    fdRead1 = fopen("parent1.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mut1);
        size = fread(buf,128,1,fdRead1);
        fwrite(buf,size,1,fd);
        pthread_cond_signal(cond_var);
    cout<<"W2Thread-1"<<endl; 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mut1);
        sleep(10);
    }
    fclose(fdRead1);

}

void* W2(void *)
{
    char buf[128];
    int size;
    fdRead2 = fopen("parent2.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mut1);
        size = fread(buf,128,1,fdRead2);
        fwrite(buf,size,1,fd);
        pthread_cond_signal(cond_var);
    cout<<"W2Thread-1"<<endl; 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mut1);
        sleep(1000);

    }
    fclose(fdRead2);

}


int main()
{
int des_cond, des_msg, des_mutex;
int mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG;

des_mutex = shm_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, mode);

if (des_mutex < 0) {
    perror("failure on shm_open on des_mutex");
    exit(1);
}

if (ftruncate(des_mutex, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)) == -1) {
    perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
    exit(-1);
}

mut1 = (pthread_mutex_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t),
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_mutex, 0);

if (mut1 == MAP_FAILED ) {
    perror("Error on mmap on mutex\n");
    exit(1);
}

des_cond = shm_open(OKTOWRITE, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, mode);

if (des_cond < 0) {
    perror("failure on shm_open on des_cond");
    exit(1);
}

if (ftruncate(des_cond, sizeof(pthread_cond_t)) == -1) {
    perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
    exit(-1);
}

cond_var = (pthread_cond_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_cond_t),
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_cond, 0);

if (cond_var == MAP_FAILED ) {
    perror("Error on mmap on condition\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Initialise attribute to mutex. */
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrmutex);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attrmutex, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

/* Allocate memory to pmutex here. */

/* Initialise mutex. */
pthread_mutex_init(mut1, &attrmutex);
/* Initialise attribute to condition. */
pthread_condattr_init(&attrcond);
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&attrcond, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

/* Allocate memory to pcond here. */

/* Initialise condition. */
pthread_cond_init(cond_var, &attrcond);



    pthread_t thR1,thR2,thW1,thW2;
    fd = fopen("a.txt","w+");
    int res = fork();
    if(res<0) perror("error forking\n");
    if(res==0)//child
    {
        cout<<"child created"<<endl;
        pthread_create(&thR1,0,R1,0);
        //pthread_create(&thR2,0,R2,0);
        pthread_join(thR1,0);
        //pthread_join(thR2,0);
        fclose(fd);
    }
    else//parent
    {
        //fdRead = fopen("parent.txt","r");
        pthread_create(&thW1,0,W1,0);
        //pthread_create(&thW2,0,W2,0);
        pthread_join(thW1,0);
        //pthread_join(thW2,0);
        fclose(fd);
        wait(0);
    } 
}
```

The output is as follows-

```
child created
W2Thread-1
R1Thread
R1Thread-1
W2Thread-1
W2Thread-1
W2Thread-1
W2Thread-1
W2Thread-1
W2Thread-1
W2Thread-1
W2Thread-1
```

The condition_wait in child never comes out.

Comment: Forking a `pthread` code is a [minefield](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them).

Comment: Yes, @user58697, but this code forks while the parent has only one thread, and outside of any critical section.  That's a safe case.

Answer (score 1):

There are potential issues with using multiple processes, each with multiple threads, but they mostly revolve around program state at the time of the fork.  Since your program forks before it creates any additional threads, you can be confident about its state at that time, and in particular, you can be confident that its one thread is not at that time executing in a critical section.  This is fine.

However, you are missing two key details:

1. Although you set the mutex to be process-shared, the version of the code you initially presented failed to do the same for the condition variable.
2. Setting `pthread_*` synchronization objects to be process-shared is necessary, but not sufficient, for inter-process use.  For that, you need the synchronization objects to reside in shared memory accessed by all participating processes.  Only that way can all the process access the same objects.

Comment: I used shm_open,mmap,ftruncate; still no progress, can you check my modified code

Comment: @Sandeep SO is not an iterative debugging/development service.  If you keep editing the question code, you will confuse current users and will end up invalidating existing answers/comments :(